# How to change color of listview rows based on bindig value in xamarin form

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a listview in which i have data, in listview i have

**1 -** taskname

**2-** date

**3 -** completed percentage

**4 -** Assigned task by

I want to put condition in list and based on condition  want to change color of list row, for example if completed percentage `=0`, color of that row should be `white` if percentage is greater then `0` color should be red etc etc.

**check image down below:**

[image: List Example]

in listview i have 0%, 7% and 100 %, so i want if its 0 row color should be white, if its more then 0 row color should b red and if its = 100 row color should be green here is my xaml code

```
 <ListView   HeightRequest="20"  HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorColor="Red" ItemsSource="{Binding GetAssignedTask}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>


                            <ViewCell >
                                <Grid  >
                                   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Source="rsz_pnglogocom.png"  />
                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding strTaskName}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" />
                                    <Label  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding intCurrCompletePercentage , StringFormat='{0}% Completed '}" Margin="0,0,10,0"  TextColor="Black" />

                                    <Label  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,20,0"  Text="{Binding dtStart,StringFormat='{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}'}"  TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

                                    <Label   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding strAssignedByEmpName}" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Comment: There are two ways to do this. You can use a value converter and based on your value return the BackgroundColor, but this does not work if your values are changed dynamically being on the same page as Converters are only fired once. So you can create a background property in your binding object which returns the Color object based on your values.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at `DataTemplateSelector` for this case.
A look in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector

Code from documentation

```
public class PersonDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ValidTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate InvalidTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate (object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        return ((Person)item).DateOfBirth.Year >= 1980 ? ValidTemplate : InvalidTemplate;
    }
 }
```

XAML

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="validPersonTemplate">
                <ViewCell>
                   ...
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="invalidPersonTemplate">
                <ViewCell>
                   ...
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            <local:PersonDataTemplateSelector x:Key="personDataTemplateSelector"
                ValidTemplate="{StaticResource validPersonTemplate}"
                InvalidTemplate="{StaticResource invalidPersonTemplate}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource personDataTemplateSelector}" />
```

You would have to make 3 templates (ZeroTemplate, AboveZeroTemplate, HundredTemplate) and let your `DataTemplateSelector` decide which template it should take.

I posted just the documentation code, because I think you always should do something on yourself to also learn something, and not just copy paste.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this.
1. Using Converters:

Create a Value converter:

```
public class BackgroundColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            if(value!=null)
            {
                if((int)value ==0)
                    return Color.White;
                else if((int)value > 0)
                    return Color.Red;
                else 
                    return Color.Green;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return null;
    }


    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

xaml part:

```
xmlns:converter="RefrenceToConverterNameSpace"
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converter:BackgroundColorConverter x:Key="BackgroundColorConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<Grid BackgroundColor="{Binding intCurrCompletePercentage,Converter={StaticResource BackgroundColorConverter}}" />
```

Method 2:

In your object which containts `intCurrCompletePercentage`
You can also have another property Color property `PercentColor`

```
public Color PercentColor
{
    get
    {
        if(intCurrCompletePercentage ==0)
            return Color.White;
        else if(intCurrCompletePercentage > 0)
            return Color.Green;
        else 
            return Color.Red;
    }
}

<Grid BackgroundColor="{Binding PercentColor}" />
```

Whenever your intCurrCompletePercentage  changes dont forget to call the propertychanged event for PercentColor.